# I want to use cout more comfortably

Tags: c++, cout

[image]

I want to use `cout` to print out this sentence: "You can build piramid which floor is only odd. not even", but I want to do it more comfortably. Just like the way below. But, when I use this way, an error occurs. So, is there any way to use it like this?

```
cout << "You can build piramid which floor is only odd.
        not even" << '\n';
```

Comment: Either split the sentence by `<<` or use `\` to concatenate two lines. Note if you're using `\`, then the indent would be counted as output text as well.  Eg: `"... only odd." << "not even"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjacent [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) will automatically be concatenated, even if they are on different lines. So you can write it this way instead:

```
std::cout << "You can only build pyramids whose floor is odd, "
             "not even.\n";
```

Comment: Thx for your help. hav a nice day Wenzel~

Answer (score 2):

To use multi-line strings in C++, you *can* use backslash.

```
 cout << "You can build piramid which floor is only odd. \
not even" << '\n';
```

Comment: Thx for your help. hav a nice day akaAbdullahMateen~